# I'm getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while initializing ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient object

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, solrj, solr5

I'm getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while initializing ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient object by calling

```
ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient _server = new ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient(url, 10, 4);
```

Jar files which I'm using are

```
httpcore-4.4.1.jar
httpclient-4.4.1.jar
```

The following error logged in console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.util.VersionInfo.getUserAgent(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.setDefaultHttpParams(DefaultHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.createHttpParams(DefaultHttpClient.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getParams(AbstractHttpClient.java:466)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.setFollowRedirects(HttpClientUtil.java:290)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientConfigurer.configure(HttpClientConfigurer.java:58)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.configureClient(HttpClientUtil.java:149)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:125)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.<init>(HttpSolrClient.java:188)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.<init>(HttpSolrClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.<init>(ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.<init>(ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.java:119)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.<init>(ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.java:109)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.<init>(ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.java:102)
    at com.etl.extract.ExtractData.<init>(ExtractData.java:34)
    at com.etl.base.LaunchExtract.main(LaunchExtract.java:11)
```

Please let me know if anyone already faced this issue and resolved!

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to put your jars to your build path

Comment: Thanks, But I have added all the jars in  java buildpath. Still I'm getting this issue. I'm running this through standalone java application ( from main(...) method)

Comment: Are you using the solr-solrj-jar?

Comment: Yes, using solr-solrj-5.5.0.jar which also in the buildpath.

Comment: Why do you need the jars httpcore-4.4.1.jar, httpclient-4.4.1.jar? Can you remove them and test again?

Comment: working now!!!!!! I just removed and added the jars in the class path. Wondering!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yes, It worked for me as well. I'm using solr-6.1.0. When I removed the 2 jars, the issue got resolved.